# Finding out if a person has passed or failed (using recursive functions)

Tags: python, list

We are supposed to input a list of a person's marks and if any member of the list is <40 the person fails else they pass. I was able to solve this problem without any issues, but was wondering if this code can be made more crisp as this is my first time dealing with recursive functions.

```
    l = eval(input()) 
    def duck(i,f):
    if i < len(l): 
     if l[i] >= 40:
       f = f+1
       i = i+1
       return duck(i,f)
    else:
        d = 'Fail'
        print(d)
        quit()
    if f == len(l):
       print('Pass')
        
   duck(0,0)
```

I am sharing some I/O samples as well:

Input `[55,56,76,89,62]`

Output `Pass`

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: Please provide examples of input/output

Comment: yes I know about the eval issue, but my college recommends to use it for most of the practice cases.

Comment: @mozway I have added a sample input/output

Comment: Thanks @Sayse from the next time I'll seek help there.

Comment: It should return 'True' or 'False', depending on the result we'll change the output to 'Pass' or 'Fail'

Comment: @Singularity just for fun: `'Fail' if any(map((40).__gt__, eval(input()))) else 'Pass'` (remember that *eval is evil*) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a list of scores, you can do recursion as follows:

```py
def duck(lst):
    return lst[0] >= 40 and duck(lst[1:]) if lst else True

print(duck([35, 94, 56, 10])) # False
print(duck([55, 56, 76, 89, 62])) # True
```

---

As per the OP's request:

Here, `A if {condition} else B` syntax is called [*conditional expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions): the expression evaluates to `A` if `{condition}` is `True`, and `B` otherwise.

Using this, you can print `'Pass'` or `'Fail'` according to the result:

```py
print('Pass' if duck([55, 56, 76, 89, 62]) else 'Fail') # Pass
```

Here the function output is `True`, so the condition is `True`. Therefore the code simplifies to `print('Pass')`.

---

But really a comprehension is enough:

```py
def duck(lst):
    return all(x >= 40 for x in lst)
```

Comment: Since I am fairly new to coding, can you please explain the use of *is_pass what does '*' do here? Also can you explain how have you used if and else in a single line without using :? sorry for such basic questions, I am still fairly new to this and have not learnt about this representation.

Comment: @Singularity I've added the second part to the answer. What is the first part? Ah I guess that was `*`. That is called _unpacking_. The revised version does not have that, but if you are interested in that, please look into it. Unpacking is very useful.